# Associate child categories only to an entry

Tags: categories, relations

When adding a Categories field to a section, if you select only child categories, Craft automatically selects the parent categories too. I emailed Craft support about this and they explained it's by design and the workaround is to use a Structure instead of Categories.

I'm unhappy with this as a workaround and was hoping their was another way to do this, either with a custom plugin or something else?

Any help much appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to workaround this by creating my own custom fieldtype which is 99% the code from the Craft CategoriesFieldType, but with the only difference being I removed the call to `craft()->categories->fillGapsInCategoryIds($categoryIds)`.

This works but I've yet to see if it causes any side-effects I need to worry about.

Comment: FWIW, this is solved in the upcoming Craft 3 with the concept of category field branch limits.  Allows you to set how far up the category tree to select (if at all).

Comment: James, would you mind throwing this modified field type on a public repo somewhere?

Comment: @James, do you have the modified fieldtype you could post somewhere? Thanks.